How to search using full path in Workspace folders in Visual Studio Code?
For simplicity, lets say my workspace in VSCode consists of three directories, being code, doc, and tests. When trying to search for a file using CTRL+P, I used to be able to use the relative path of the file, such as code/main.py.
However, ever since we started splitting the folders inside the workspace to Source, Documentation, and Testing, the search for code/main.py does not yield the file anymore since VSCode does not recognize its path.
We can now use Source/main.py instead, but this is especially annoying when trying to copy a file from a pull request since the file won't be found.
Is there a way to fix this issue? Since we currently are thinking of dropping the usage of Workspaces altogether.

I don't see any "issue" to fix here other than trying to remember new path, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

The file code/main.py is still in the same path as it always was, but now trying to open the file using its path does not work since VSCode does not recognize the file to be in the same path but rather in the workspace folder. So, I can open the file with code/main.py as usual without opening the workspace.

And which workspace are you doing this from? Your question could be phrased a lot better. Show us the overall structure of folders and from where the search is done.

All the directories are in the root folder of the project, and the search location is irrelevant since CTRL+P in VSCode searches all the files, regardless of location.
